# How to handle a database structure than involves different currencies

Tags: mysql, logic

I have a table in which there are two fields i.e. `exchangeRate` and `amount`
Let's say I have a currency whose exchange rate is `158` and foreign currency `amount` is `20,000`, when I convert it by doing so `(20000/158 = 126.582278481)`; 
I am storing this value `(126.582278481)` in database which doesn't seem convenient to me but anyway. 
Now the problem is that when I edit the same value by providing the user their amount i.e. `20000` by `(126.582278481 x 158 = 19999.999999998)`; it becomes `'19999.999999998'` which is not exactly `20000`; So, what should I store in DB to get the correct value?
FYI: I want the `amount` column to store, converted local currency amount, because I am using local currency amount for generating reports etc.

Comment: exchange rates are point in time. Ypu need a table that is like a Type 2 SCD

Comment: So store the amount, the currency, and the date. Separately, store the exchange rate for that date.

Comment: It's OK to store the local currency, and the foreign currency amount that was calculated at the time of the transaction in a separate column. There's no doubt then about the foreign amount.

Comment: I am storing both local and foreign currency values, but I want the best way to do it

Comment: Also, see ROUND(), of course.